# PHP echo не передает атрибут "checked" у радиокнопки

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Есть слайдер, который вытягивает картинки из БД, переключение м/у картинками должно осуществляться через переходы по радиокнопкам посредством CSS 3. Отладил все, осталось только передать значение "checked" для input'а, передачу всего HTML-каркаса слайдера осуществляю подобным образом:

```
<?php
...
echo ...
'<div id="slider">
 <input type="radio" id="button_1" name="radio_buttons" checked />
 <input type="radio" id="button_2" name="radio_buttons" />
...
 <img src="'.$foto['foto_1'].'">
...
 <img src="'.$foto['foto_2'].'">
...
 </div>';}}
?>
```

Если поменять тип у 1ой кнопки на "checkbox", то атрибут  "checked" передастся без проблем, но тогда я не смогу переключаться м/у картинками, а как передать его для "radio" я уже и не знаю?! По-моему, это какой-то фантомный баг.. в сети не нашел никакого специфического синтаксиса для радиокнопок

Готов "побыть 5 минут дураком" в ваших глазах.
Спасибо!

*многоточием обозначил куски кода, которые идут перед и после.. и никак не влияют на передачу "checked" - проверено опытным путем

Comment: А в итоговом коде страницы что? checked присутствует?

Comment: rjhdby, нет, к сожалению, на клиент "checked" не передается, НО я частично решил свою задачу, поставив заплатку на jQuery:

    var check=document.getElementsByName('radio_buttons');
    if(!check[1].checked) check[1].checked=true;

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что магии не существует? Если вы принудительно задали `checked` в строковой переменной, то он в html впечатался. Варианта, на самом деле, два: 1) У вас неправильно формируется строка(оно же в цикле, да?) - введите промежуточную переменную `$string='bla-bla';var_dump($string);echo $string;` и убедитесь, что все ок. 2) Вам вредит javascript. Ищите в своих функциях/зависимостях, которые могут снимать этот атрибут.

Comment: rjhdby, на счет магии Вы правы, как и правы на счет вывода в цикле! ;) у меня таких input'ов было много и они были для каждого выводимого div'а, откуда уже и запускался слайдер; я добавил ID'шники этих div'ов в вывод для каждого input'а и у меня все заработало, даже моя заплатка на jQuery стала не нужна, потому как работала только для 1го выводимого div'а?! Я уже было начал грешить в его сторону.. но Вы меня наставили на путь истинный! Видимо, скрипт не понимал для какого именно div'а нужно проставлять значение "checked".. в общем, Спасибо Вам БОЛЬШОЕ!!! Я не один день просидел над этим..

Comment: бывает :) Вообще, если вдруг что-то ведет себя неправильно, примите себе за правило через строчку вставлять var_dump с выводом вычисленного выше. Ооооочень помогает :)

Answer (score 2):

При таких выборах как пол - проще всего ручками  написать - всего пара input с постоянными значениями, которые не зависят от DB.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes" class="radio" <?php if (isset($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio'] == 'yes'): ?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?> /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no"  class="radio" <?php if (isset($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio'] ==  'no'): ?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?> /> No
```

Comment: ultimatum, спасибо за интересный пример ;) только это немного не то, чего бы хотелось.. моя вина - вопрос поставил несколько расплывчато и код толком не выложил (хотел поставить акцент именно на "checked") у меня input'ов гораздо больше, чем 2, и POST'ом у меня только ссылки на фото передаются, "checked" же хотел вывести через echo

Пока задачу решил кусочком jQuery-вставки, хотя до сих пор не могу понять, почему "checked" не выставляется обычным способом?!